# MySQL installation and removal issue

Tags: linux, mysql, apt

```
root@administrator-desktop:/etc/mysql# sudo apt-get remove php5-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mysql is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.1 (5.1.37-1ubuntu5.5) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mysql not found.
the process get hanged here.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script killed by signal (Interrupt)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.1; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.1
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@administrator-desktop:/etc/mysql#
```

please help what is the issues.
I am  facing this in too many places

Answer (score 2):

The problem there is that there seems to be a broken install of the package mysql-server-5.1.

Try using

```
dpkg -r mysql-server-5.1
apt-get install mysql-server-5.1
```

To remove and reinstall. If dpkg refuses to remove, try adding --force flag (and see dpkg --force-help for more help)

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a file /etc/init.d/mysql

```
touch /etc/init.d/mysql
```

And now remove the mysql-server-5.1

Then you can reinstall it.

Blog : http://linuxdump.com/?p=89

Comment: I know this is kind of late but, I had a similar problem. The following line tells the problem:
...invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mysql not found...
I did what Mr. Gardeniers said: "touch /etc/init.d/mysql" afterwards I was able to remove/reinstall the package.
-J